# Interconnected curved lines

Tags: javascript, algorithm, drawing

Given a series of JSON co-ordinates typically in the format:

```
{from: {x:0, y:0}, to: {x:0, y:10}, ...}
```

I would like to draw a series of straight dotted paths which are connected with simple, fixed radius rounded corners. I have been looking at Slope Intercept Form to calculate the points along the straight line but I am a little perplexed as to the approach for calcualting the points along the (Bezier?) curves.

e.g. I want to draw curves between p1 and p2 and p3 and p4. Despite what the poor mockup might imply I am happy for the corners to be a fixed radius e.g. 10px

[image: Path]

I would like to abstract out the drawing logic and therefore am seeking a generalised approach to returning a JavaScript point array which I can then render in a number of ways (hence I am avoiding using any inbuilt functions provided by SVG, Canvas etc).

Comment: How much computational resource are willing to put in? If you don't have any restrictions, you can fit an ellipse such that it connects p1 and p2 and its slope matches the slope of the lines.

Comment: What should be the output of your program?

Comment: "dotted lines (points), which are connected with corners" - what does it mean?

Comment: Amended the description slightly - does that help? Output should be an array of x,y co-ordinates representing points along the path.

Comment: What should be the output? Should it be rasterized an image (pixel grid) ? But what this means "returning a JavaScript point array" ?

Comment: You also write "draw straight dotted paths", then you write "calculating the points along the (Bezier?) curves" ? There are so many contradictions in your question...

Comment: I'd hope the diagram would help - certainly it helped Pataschu propose a solution. The output is an array of points which represent the complete path - as per my last comment I am trying to abstract out the rendering method at this point. I want to draw a series of lines (as per the diagram) and connect them with curves, however I dont want to draw the curves I simply want the points along the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a cubic bezier curve.

http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/splines/

Look at the first applet on this page. If A is p1, D is p2, the direction A-B is line 1's angle and the direction C-D is line 2's angle you can see how this gives you the properties you need - it starts at angle 1 and ends at angle 2 and is flush with the points.

So, to get your points C and D, one way to do this would be to take the line segment 1, copy it, place it starting at p1 - and say where the new line ends is B, and similar with line segment 2 and p2 for D. (And you could do things like have a factor that multiplies into the copied line segments' distance to make the curves stick out more or less... etc)

Then just do the math :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves

And once you have your equation for the curve, step through it with a delta t of the desired precision (e.g. every 0.1 of t, every 0.01...) and spit out every pair of points on the curve as a line segment.

Comment: Your link shows interpolation of function of one real variable, not interpolation of curve. (There is (x2-x1) in denominator)

Comment: @Ivan Kuckir You are correct, I am embarrassed. I will look for a better algorithm.

Comment: BTW. I know it, because I was implementing it :) http://blog.ivank.net/interpolation-with-cubic-splines.html

Photoshop curves use that interpolation.

Comment: @Ivan Kuckir I edited my answer with the correct curve to use

Comment: @Patashu I'm following this question of shared interest. Can you please clarify something for me - When plugging numbers into the explicit form of the Bézier curve, from the wikipedia article, what do P0 - P3 stand for? X values of those points? Where do their Y values come into play?

Comment: @OpherV P is a tuple of (Px,Py). Meaning you do the equation for all the xs then all the ys (because at least for this equation, they do not interact with each other). Messing around with the applet confirms this - moving any points only on x never changes the y positions and vice versa.